# Login Stack Overflow with Elinks

Tags: discussion, login, captcha

Just for the sport: is it possible to login Stack Overflow with Elinks? Appearently, it accepts my credentials, but then it requires a CAPTCHA test that, clearly, is not an obvious matter with a text based browser.

How can I see the CAPTCHA? Is it worth the effort, in term of PC alphabetization, to perform such kind of operations?

[image: elinks]

Comment: *Please don't take this personally* ... Makes me think if anyone has ever felt offended just because they were shown a CAPTCHA.

Comment: Of course I will not, thanks for your courtesy. It is just a trivial curiosity. I was wondering on how to deal with a captcha in a text based browser.

Comment: Erm @Worice, I was just speaking about the line shown on the CAPTCHA page. It was not related to you at all! :)

Comment: That is embarrassing! I do apologize for such a misunderstand :)

Comment: Elinks is not in the list of [supported browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). That said, you do [not always](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear) need to complete a Captcha in order to login.

Comment: @Glorfindel, according to the list, should I consider any text based browser unusable with SO? Second, what should I do when a website, like in this case, uses a captcha?

Comment: @Worice sorry, I don't have any experience with text based browsers. I'm just stating what I do know ...

Comment: It is ok, thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is: give up and use a proper browser...

Comment: @BhargavRao I heard that cloudflare offended plenty of people with their captchas...

Comment: You might be able to log in, then copy over the cookies.

Comment: Interestingly, [Elinks can be built with some kind of Javascript support](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34687/is-there-a-text-mode-browser-which-supports-javascript), and it might not be the only text-mode browser with JS support.  (I suspect that JS support is essential for a lot of SO activities, although I haven't tried without.)

Comment: I can imagine wanting to use a text-based browser to ask a question on Super User or Unix&Linux.SE if [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) won't start.

Comment: @PeterCordes: UI operations more complicated than scrolling and clicking normal links require JS, by and large. All moderation is included in that, and I don't believe the editor works well at all without JS either. (I use NoScript, and a couple of the less common SE domains, like AU's, aren't whitelisted, so I get the JS error banner when I visit them. Haven't tried submitting an edit or post though, so I don't know about the editor for sure.)